# services failing to start - control process exited with error code

Tags: server, apache2, 18.04, services, snap

I recently upgraded to 18.04
Initially everything went smooth but now services are failing to start...

Firslty snapd.service stopped working. Following was the error when i ran
**systemctl start snapd.service** :

> Job for snapd.service failed because the control process exited with
>   error code. See "systemctl status snapd.service" and "journalctl -xe"
>   for details.

**systemctl status snapd.service** returns this:

> ● snapd.service - Snappy daemon    Loaded: loaded
>   (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
>   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-06-25 16:40:19 IST;
>   4min 16   Process: 17034 ExecStart=/usr/lib/snapd/snapd (code=exited,
>   status=1/FAILURE)  Main PID: 17034 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>
> Jun 25 16:40:19 shubhamubuntu systemd[1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1592503): snapd.service: Service
>   hold-off time o Jun 25 16:40:19 shubhamubuntu systemd[1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1592503):
>   snapd.service: Scheduled restart job,  Jun 25 16:40:19 shubhamubuntu
>   systemd[1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1592503): Stopped Snappy daemon. Jun 25 16:40:19 shubhamubuntu
>   systemd[1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1592503): snapd.service: Start request repeated  Jun 25 16:40:19
>   shubhamubuntu systemd[1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1592503): snapd.service: Failed with result 'exi Jun
>   25 16:40:19 shubhamubuntu systemd[1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1592503): Failed to start Snappy daemon.

**journalctl -xe** returns this:

> -- Subject: Unit snapd.service has finished shutting down
>   -- Defined-By: systemd
>
> ### -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
>
> -- Unit snapd.service has finished shutting down. Jun 25 16:53:01 shubhamubuntu systemd[1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1592503): snapd.service: Start request repeated  Jun
>   25 16:53:01 shubhamubuntu systemd[1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1592503): snapd.service: Failed with
>   result 'exi Jun 25 16:53:01 shubhamubuntu systemd[1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1592503): Failed to start
>   Snappy daemon.
>   -- Subject: Unit snapd.service has failed
>   -- Defined-By: systemd
>
> ### -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
>
> ### -- Unit snapd.service has failed.
>
> -- The result is RESULT. Jun 25 16:53:01 shubhamubuntu systemd[1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1592503): snapd.socket: Failed with result 'serv Jun 25 16:53:22 shubhamubuntu
>   google-chrome.desktop[2586]: [2586:2586:0625/16532 Jun 25 16:53:52
>   shubhamubuntu sudo[17595]: shubhamg931 : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/s Jun
>   25 16:53:52 shubhamubuntu sudo[17595]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session
>   opene Jun 25 16:53:52 shubhamubuntu sudo[17595]:
>   pam_unix(sudo:session): session close Jun 25 16:55:01 shubhamubuntu
>   CRON[17614]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opene Jun 25 16:55:01
>   shubhamubuntu CRON[17615]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > / Jun
>   25 16:55:01 shubhamubuntu CRON[17614]: pam_unix(cron:session): session
>   close Jun 25 16:55:52 shubhamubuntu gnome-keyring-daemon[2207]: asked
>   to register item lines 1905-1928/1928 (END)

I thought it was only for snapd.service but now when today I ran  **systemctl start apache2** same error came:

> Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with
>   error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl
>   -xe" for details.

**systemctl status apache2.service** returns this:

> ● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server    Loaded: loaded
>   (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset:
>   Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
>              └─apache2-systemd.conf    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-06-25 16:36:37 IST; 8min ag   Process: 16268
>   ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=1/FAILUR
>   Process: 10629 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful (code=exited,
>   status=0/   Process: 16767 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start
>   (code=exited, status=1/FAIL  Main PID: 11147 (code=exited,
>   status=0/SUCCESS)
>
> Jun 25 16:36:37 shubhamubuntu systemd[1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1592503): Starting The Apache HTTP
>   Server... Jun 25 16:36:37 shubhamubuntu apachectl[16767]: AH00526:
>   Syntax error on line 16 Jun 25 16:36:37 shubhamubuntu
>   apachectl[16767]: Header has too many arguments Jun 25 16:36:37
>   shubhamubuntu apachectl[16767]: Action 'start' failed. Jun 25 16:36:37
>   shubhamubuntu apachectl[16767]: The Apache error log may have mo Jun
>   25 16:36:37 shubhamubuntu systemd[1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1592503): apache2.service: Control process
>   exite Jun 25 16:36:37 shubhamubuntu systemd[1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1592503): apache2.service:
>   Failed with result 'e Jun 25 16:36:37 shubhamubuntu systemd[1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1592503): Failed
>   to start The Apache HTTP Server

**journalctl -xe** returns this:

> Jun 25 17:01:46 shubhamubuntu anacron[17739]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
>   Jun 25 17:03:05 shubhamubuntu polkitd(authority=local)[1214]:
>   Registered Authent Jun 25 17:03:09 shubhamubuntu
>   polkitd(authority=local)[1214]: Operator of unix-s Jun 25 17:03:09
>   shubhamubuntu systemd[1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1592503): Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
>   -- Subject: Unit apache2.service has begun start-up
>   -- Defined-By: systemd
>
> ### -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
>
> -- Unit apache2.service has begun starting up. Jun 25 17:03:09 shubhamubuntu apachectl[17768]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 16 Jun
>   25 17:03:09 shubhamubuntu apachectl[17768]: Header has too many
>   arguments Jun 25 17:03:09 shubhamubuntu apachectl[17768]: Action
>   'start' failed. Jun 25 17:03:09 shubhamubuntu apachectl[17768]: The
>   Apache error log may have mo Jun 25 17:03:09 shubhamubuntu systemd[1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1592503):
>   apache2.service: Control process exite Jun 25 17:03:09 shubhamubuntu
>   systemd[1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1592503): apache2.service: Failed with result 'e Jun 25 17:03:09
>   shubhamubuntu systemd[1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1592503): Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server
>   -- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
>   -- Defined-By: systemd
>
> ### -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
>
> ### -- Unit apache2.service has failed.
>
> -- The result is RESULT. Jun 25 17:03:09 shubhamubuntu polkitd(authority=local)[1214]: Unregistered Authe lines
>   1924-1947/1947 (END)

I referred to following thread: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1592503
but they also do not seem to reach any conclusion before the thread expired.

UPDATE:
**sudo apt install --reinstall snapd** returns:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1
>   reinstalled, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded. Need to get 0 B/12.2 MB
>   of archives. After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will
>   be used. (Reading database ... 197446 files and directories currently
>   installed.) Preparing to unpack .../snapd_2.32.9+18.04_amd64.deb ...
>   Unpacking snapd (2.32.9+18.04) over (2.32.9+18.04) ... Setting up
>   snapd (2.32.9+18.04) ... snapd.snap-repair.service is a disabled or a
>   static unit, not starting it. Job for snapd.service failed because the
>   control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status
>   snapd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details. Job for
>   snapd.seeded.service failed because the control process exited with
>   error code. See "systemctl status snapd.seeded.service" and
>   "journalctl -xe" for details. Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2)
>   ...

Comment: Where are the `journalctl -xe` messages!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen i have updated the messages in question

Comment: For apache `Syntax error on line 16`, and for snapd try to re-install `sudo apt install --reinstall snapd`

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen i have update the error for sudo apt install --reinstall snapd